# html description keywords

Tags: html, keyword

when i search for my site on google all i get is this.

Index of /
Index of /. cgi-bin/ · css/ · db_con.php · images/ · js/ · testing.php.

I have updated the description and keywords but i was wondering how long it would take before this gets updated? the alexa rank is around 400k atm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Google Webmaster Tools you can get plenty of info on when your content was last indexed. take a look at https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Typically, it can take a couple of weeks to get refreshed meta information onto Google, as a rough guide. Looking at Webmaster Tools will tell you exactly (once it's been running for a little while)